# Mapnik - couldnt create conventer for s

Tags: python, xml, runtime-error, rendering, mapnik

Hi I have simple python script for `mapnik`, which use `xml` style. It is working correctly on windows where I have `mapnik 2.2.0` but on Linux debian I have `mapnik 3.0.12` and I got this error:

```
mapnik.render_to_file(m, 'msk.png', 'png') could not create conventer for s.
```

Where the problem might be ??

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

Please check read/write permission to the file you are writing to. In UNIX environment you must have proper read/write permission to read or write to a file.